# Hubspot API - list of properties needed (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, api, crm, hubspot

I am integrating the hubspot API to track user interaction with our site. I am creating dynamic lists and I want to filter a user into a certain contact list by which URL they visit.

```
"filters": [
            [

                {
                    "operator": "CONTAINS",
                    "property": "hs_URL",
                    "value": `${id}`
                },
            ],
        ]
```

I keep getting this error for all my attempts:

`{"status":"error","message":"Couldn't find a Property with the given name 'hs_URL'","correlationId":"0723dcee-534b-4f92-9104-509d6885abbe","propertiesErrorCode":"PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND"}`,

I cannot seem to find a master property list and have tried many string combinations. Anyone familiar with hubspot property lists would be my savior.

Thank you~!

Answer (score 3):

It's been a few months, so you may not need this anymore, but since I landed here while looking for a way to get all the properties from an object type in hubspot using nodejs, this might help others looking for the solution.

The master list of properties can be retrieved with the following API call:

```
const response = await hubspotClient.crm.properties.coreApi.getAll(objectType, false);
```

The arguments for **getAll()** expect:

1. **objectType**: a string, i.e "contacts".
2. **archived**: a boolean, i.e *false*. Set this *true* if you want to get archived properties.

The following code was adapted based on this page from the hubspot API docs:
https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/properties

Once you're on the page, you can click on the "Endpoints" Tab to reveal code snippets for multiple environments, including nodejs.

For this example, **getProperties()**, retrieves all properties for a given object type. I used contacts for the object type, which I believe is where you are storing the url property, but you could use the same function to get properties for other object types such as companies or deals.

It might be worth noting that I mapped the results to return just the property names, which sounds like all you need for your case, but more information is contained in the results if you need it. Just remove this bit to get more information on each property:

```
.map(prop => prop.name)
```

```
const hubspot = require('@hubspot/api-client')
const hubspotClient = new hubspot.Client({ apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY" })

const getProperties = async (objectType) => {
  try {
    const response = await hubspotClient.crm.properties.coreApi.getAll(objectType, false);
    return response.body.results.map(prop => prop.name);
  } catch (e) {
    e.message === 'HTTP request failed'
      ? console.error(JSON.stringify(e.response, null, 2))
      : console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Here's an example for running the function to get a list of all property names for contacts.

```
(async () => {
  var properties = await getProperties("contacts");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(properties ,null,2));
})();
```

It took me a bit to find this, so figured I would post here in the hopes it saves time for someone else. This is the first time I've posted a solution, and I'm pretty new to this API and Hubspot in general, so feedback and/or better solutions are welcome. Cheers.